# Overwrite outdated tiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, map-service

I have a map service on a local server (marked 2) and a raster (marked1). [image]

I want to add the raster to the service, ovewriting the existing data. To do so I right click the map service in the catalog choose `Mange Cache`, then `Mange Tiles`In `Update Mode` I select `RECREATE_ALL_TILES` and set the area of interest to the extent of the raster's extent.
Nothing happens, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the share as service dialogue, instead of creating a new service, select overwrite and select your existing service. The data in your table of contents will be used to overwrite the service

Comment: The thing is I don't want to make the map service from scratch (don't have original MXD) and I want to save the cashing that was defined.